# How to remove all data about some Web Application from aspnet tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql

Is there some way to remove data about all users , roles e t c from some Web application into aspnet database tables ?

tables like dbo.aspnet_Applications (here is this application that I want to remove)

but also I need to remove all data with this application in other tables...

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Log? Dump? And what is a "Web application", in opposed to "aspnet database tables"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, surely if you have the ID of the application you wish to delete, you can just use that key to delete from all the other relevant tables? It should all be linked. What problem are you having?